# Casting a POD struct into a derived type

Tags: c++, struct, casting, legacy-code, memory-layout

While working on a legacy projectr I came across the following pattern: 
a POD struct is used to transfer data over the network.

```
struct PODType {
    // some data
    int data;
};
```

On the receiver side, the data is received into an object of the POD type. Later on, a class is derived from the PODType and the received object is casted with a C-style cast into the derived class to use some methods accessing the data.

```
class DerivedFromPOD: public PODType {
public:
    // some methods
    int f(int x) {return data+x;}
protected:
    // some methods
};

PODType pod;
receive(&pod);

DerivedFromPOD* d = (DerivedFromPOD*)&pod;
int i = d->f(10);
```

The derived class has public and protected methods, so it is not a POD anymore. I know that this is an abuse of inheritance, but it has been in the code base for a long time.

I am wondering if that is guaranteed to work from a standard point of view (C++03 or C++98). The derived class does not have any own data members or virtual functions, but I am not sure if it guaranteed that the memory layout is identical given that one is POD and the other is not. Is the compiler forced to arrange DerivedFromPOD such that `d.data`'s address is identical to the address of an object d of DerivedFromPOD type, as it is for the POD base-class?

Comment: *"and it is not even standard-layout in C++11 terms"* Huh? Why not? As far as I can see, both `PODType` and `DerivedFromPOD` are PODs in C++11.

Comment: How a data structure is laid out in memory depends on the behaviour of the compiler and the ABI, the standard doesn't guarantee that . I think that in this case a pointer to an incomplete type can be more advantageous . Also remember that a C-style cast in C++ is a really bad thing in general.

Comment: This causes undefined behaviour according to the strict aliasing rules.

Comment: @dyp Misread section 9.7 "has the same access control [...] for all non-static data members,". Will edit the post.

Comment: @dyp But as I now looked at the source code again, I realized I overlooked the definition of a member (the class is actually quite large) which is certainly a non-POD type and thus my PODType is also a non-POD.

Comment: Can you change DerivedFromPOD to have a PODType as a member, and then construct from the PODType? That would be much safer, and shouldn't be that hard.

Comment: That is what I already proposed, but I am not sure I can do that right now. The source code does not belong to us but to a customer, and we should not change code without having a bug ticket related to it. I know it is not optimal and there are many more problems in the code, but that is the way the customer wants it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's certainly not guaranteed to work in general (try adding a virtual function to the derived class), and is formally undefined behavior.  (I also don't see how a `struct` can be used to help transfer data over the network.  Different machines will represent it differently.)

Answer (score 1):

A `DerivedFromPOD*` pointer can be cast safely into a `PODType*` pointer.
So we are assured that the layout of the inherited `PODType` in memory is the same.

However, when casting in the opposite direction, `DerivedFromPOD` can be composed in memory with some compiler data, then the `PODType` data, then some additional compiler data.

If you're using the C-style cast, or `static_cast<>` for this cast, the compiler will assume you know what you're doing and adjust the pointer address so that the `PODType` part of the `DerivedFromPOD` will correctly point to the good area.

However don't try to use methods that will access other data from `DerivedFromPOD` as they won't be correct in memory.

In particular, don't use any virtual methods as the VMT *(Virtual Method Table)* is not there.

Comment: he is casting the other way, from PODType to Derived.  Also, the class is not polymorphic so it has no vtable.

Comment: Read my answer thoroughly. I started with the way it is safe, also as an answer related to its question about the layout in memory. Then I answer about the PODType -> Derived cast.
My line about virtual method doesn't apply here but I wanted it to be a complete answer.

Comment: I don't see where you answer about the PODType->Derived cast. Paras 1-3 talk about Derived->Pod , and para 4 is unclear.